# Repeater split after X returned results

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code that outputs a number of list items `<li>` wrapped within a `UL`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RT_Footer" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <ul class="ftr-links"></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HL_NAV" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PageName") %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>'></asp:HyperLink></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

After 7 items are repeated id like to then wrap the next 7 within another UL, is this possible?

Im not a .net developer and Ive been left with the website built by an existing developer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ListView` is better suited for this than `Repeater`: It offers to repeat a configurable count of items in a group.

```
<asp:ListView ID="RT_Footer" runat="server" GroupItemCount="7">

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul runat="server" id="groupPlaceholder" />
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <GroupTemplate>
        <ul class="ftr-links">
            <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </GroupTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HL_NAV" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PageName") %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>' />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

If you need, you can even throw in a `<GroupSeparatorTemplate>` to go between your groups.